# Nested array parsing

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am parsing nested array but getting ReferenceError: player is not defined . I have state variable players which is json array as follows :

```
[
  {
    "game": "badminton",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "game": "football",
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      },
      {
        "name": "Hitesh",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/aBpM49y.jpg",
        "points": "1034.67",
        "rank": "1",
        "profile": "/hitesh"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am parsing it inside render function and creating a  card based UI element for my view as follows :

```
render(){
  //  console.log(this.players);
    var topplayers=[];
    this.state.players.map(function(game,index){
      topplayers.push(<div class="row" style={styles.row}>
        <div class="col">
          {game.game} Legend in Bangalore
        </div>
      </div>);
      const row=<div class="row">;
      topplayers.push({row});
      game.players.map(function(player,index){
        topplayers.push(<div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={player.url} alt="200-200" style={styles.image}/>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">{player.name}</h4>
              <div >
                <div style={styles.div}><img src="../../images/points.png" style={styles.rankimg}/>{player.points}</div>
                <div style={styles.div}><img src="../../images/rank.png" style={styles.rankimg}/>{player.rank}</div>
              </div>
              <a href="{player.profile}" style={styles.profile} class="btn btn-primary">View Profile</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>)
      }
    )
      const rowend=</div>;
      topplayers.push({rowend})
    }
    )

    return(
      <div>
        {topplayers}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But I am getting error ReferenceError: player is not defined . can someone help me where am I making mistake.

Comment: this.state.players.map(function(game,index){}) why are you doing players.map and naming the input parameter to the function "game"?

Comment: I would suggest that you console write out the state, i.e console.log(this.state.players) and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the const variables declared.
`const row=<div class="row">` Here, div is marking start of html and
`const rowend=</div>`;  here is ending tag.

So, everything in between is considered plain html. The map function is not behaving as a function but plain html. And that's why when player is put inside {}, javascript is trying to find the variable which doesn't exists.

Basically, in your code; everything written between `<div class="row">` and `</div>` is considered html

To make it work, you need to restructure the code to something like this:

```
render(){
//  console.log(this.players);
  var topplayers=[];
  this.state.players.map(function(game,index){
  topplayers.push(<div class="row" style={styles.row}>
    <div class="col">
      {game.game} Legend in Bangalore
    </div>
  </div>
  );
  const row=<div class="row">
    {game.players.map(function(player,index){
      return (<div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src={player.url} alt="200-200" style={styles.image}/>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{player.name}</h4>
            <div >
              <div style={styles.div}><img src="../../images/points.png" style={styles.rankimg}/>{player.points}</div>
              <div style={styles.div}><img src="../../images/rank.png" style={styles.rankimg}/>{player.rank}</div>
            </div>
            <a href="{player.profile}" style={styles.profile} class="btn btn-primary">View Profile</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
      })
    }
  </div>;
  topplayers.push(row)
})

return(
  <div>
    {topplayers}
  </div>
);
}
```

Here, I have moved the game.players.map in {} wrapped in the `<div class="row"> and </div>`. This will make sure to work it like a function. Instead of pushing result into an array, I am directly returning values from the map function which will be injected between the required divs.

Hope you understand.
Please revert in case of any doubts